# AzureRunAsConnection has not exist after create Automation account with Run As account in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I have a problem when create a Automation account in Azure with Run As account.
But the resources did not included after creating Automation account like as the following
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-create-standalone-account

In the SHARED RESOURCES of Azure pane, I checked Connections and Certificates, but AzureRunAsCertificate and AzureRunAsConnection aren't exist.

Could you please tell me why? And how to create it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally, `Azure Run As account` should be created automatically if you choose `Create Azure Run As account` to be `Yes` before creating the automation account. Did change it to be `NO` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to [have enough permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-create-standalone-account#permissions-required-to-create-an-automation-account).

Second, If you want to create a Automation account with Run As account, you need to choose `Create Azure Run As Account` to be `Yes`.

[image]

I created one in my test lab  and I  can find the connection:

[image]

Comment: For new comers, this is now not an option anymore during creation and needs to be manually added in the settings. They suggest using Identities though (but not very well documented how to use that).